# Google Authentication [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)] returns UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: .net, winapi, c#-4.0, oauth

I have a MVC 5 App which is calling a WebAPI.  The WebAPI uses bearer tokens for authentication.  There is one method(action) in the WebAPI which I want to use the token returned by Google for authentication purpose.  In order to do that I do the following to the WebAPI Method

```
[OverrideAuthentication]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("{userName}")]
public async Task<User> GetUser(string userName)
```

Despite this I still get an UNAUTHORIZED error from the WebAPI.  What do I need to do to fix this?  In addition to this when I use
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
How does the API validate the token?

Answer (score 4):

If you've provided the request you sent to this endpoint, it would be easier to answer. I suppose you don't send Authorization: Bearer header, but you send Cookie:.AspNet.ExternalCookie=, so OWIN doesn't authorize with this cookie you've obtained before (because you declare that you want your action method to be validated using Authentication header and its Bearer token).
Try to change `HostAuthentication` to this: `HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]`
and make sure you've added             `app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);`
in your OWIN `Startup`.
So how does ASP.NET (if more precise OWIN) handles authorization?
 In short: when your app starts, generally in Startup you declare what your app uses (cookies, bearer tokens, etc.). So when you call `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);` OWIN registers handlers in the pipeline. Then, regarding on what action filters you have OWIN invokes those handlers and they inspect the request context for presence of headers or cookies or whatever else (all it depends on the handler). If, let's say, CookieAuthenticationHanlder finds cookie, it then decrypts it, checks for some rules (depends on handler, CookieAuthenticationHandler checks expiration date) and passes to CookieAuthenticationProvider for extra validation. Then your request is authorized or not depending on what request contains and whether it passes through those handlers that are triggered depending on what filters you have.
I would also recommend to go through [ASP.NET Identity resources](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources), inspect some of ASP.NET Identity [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Security/Infrastructure) (I recommend to use R# in VS for inspecting the library code) and also [setup your Visual Studio](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio) and dive deep into ASP.NET Identity and OWIN debug in order to get your own picture of how the authentication pipeline works.